# reCAPTCHA not working in iOS6 UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, recaptcha

I have problems with loading reCAPTCHA with UIWebView component on iOS6.

The first time page loads fine. See screenshot for http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore.

[image]

But subsequent load requests of the **same page** have captcha image missing.

[image]

My controller code is simple:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore"]]];
}
```

and the second time this controller is loaded I have broken reCAPTCHA image.
Clearing cache with `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];` does not help. Specifying NSURLRequest cache policy like this does not work too:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[self.reCaptchaURL]
                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                           timeoutInterval:60]];
}
```

The problem is specific to iOS 6.0 and iOS 6.1. On iOS 7.0 this code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Google has fixed this bug. Now re-captcha works on iOS6.